# How do I render different components onClick? (Component should be replaced by the newest clicked handler.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I am trying to render different Components based on what navbar text I click on. Rendering the component would replace the current one. I have 5 onclick element I want to use and render 5 different components on demand. Please Help!!

```
import Sidenav from "./components/ButtonAppBar";
import AboutTab from "./components/About";
import QuoteTab from "./components/Quote";
import ProductTab from "./components/Quote";
import CalendarTab from "./components/Quote";
import ContactTab from "./components/Quote";
import "./App.css";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: "About"
    };
  }

  var component = this.state.component;

switch(component) {
  case "Contact":
    return <ContactTab />;
    break;
  case "Quote":
    return <QuoteTab />;
    break;
  default:
    return <AboutTab />;
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidenav>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            About
          </h1>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            Quote
          </h1>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            Schedule
          </h1>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            Products
          </h1>
        </Sidenav>
        <AboutTab />
        <QuoteTab />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So far I am stuck and cant get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are using the element content string, you can refactor your view like this:

```
import Sidenav from "./components/ButtonAppBar";
import AboutTab from "./components/About";
import QuoteTab from "./components/Quote";
import ProductTab from "./components/Quote";
import CalendarTab from "./components/Quote";
import ContactTab from "./components/Quote";
import "./App.css";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: "About"
        };
        this.getComponent = this.getComponent.bind(this);
    }

    getComponent(event) {
        this.setState({ component: event.target.textContent })
    }

  render() {
    const component = this.state.component;
    let renderComponent = null; // declare a null variable that will contain the component

    switch(component) {
        case "Contact":
            renderComponent = <ContactTab />;
            break;
        case "Quote":
            renderComponent = <QuoteTab />;
            break;
        default:
            renderComponent = <AboutTab />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidenav>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            About
          </h1>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            Quote
          </h1>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            Schedule
          </h1>
          <h1 className="navlink" onClick={this.getComponent}>
            Products
          </h1>
        </Sidenav>

        {/* Use the variable here */}
        {renderComponent} 

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If your nav have diferent elements than text, then, it won't work. Consider using the onClick function giving a parameter with the component name:

```
<h1 className="navlink" onClick={() => this.getComponent('About')}>
    {/* Won't work with the previous example, as it contains another html element */}
    <i className='fa fa-info' /> About
</h1>
```

and then, in the `getComponent` function:

```
getComponent(componentName) {
    this.setState({ component: componentName })
}
```

Consider also to give a more descriptive name to the function, making it easier to understand what it does (setting the component name to the state):

```
setViewComponentName(componentName) {
    this.setState({ component: componentName })
}
```